# Collect promises generated within promises in forEach

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

I want to display the progress of a migration operation to mongodb.

The script looks like:

```
let promises = [];
mylist.forEach(idx => {
    myCollection.find({id: idx}).toArray().then(msgs => {
        promises.push(myCollection2.insertMany(msgs.map(msg => ({
            msg: msg,
            otherFields: others
        }))))
    })
});

// function to display the progress:
allProgress(promises,
  (p) => {
     console.log(`% Done = ${p.toFixed(2)}`);
});
function allProgress(proms, progress_cb) {
    let d = 0;
    progress_cb(0);
    proms.forEach((p) => {
      p.then(()=> {    
        d ++;
        progress_cb( (d * 100) / proms.length );
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(proms);
}
```

This won't work because `promises` is empty when `allProgress()` is called.

How can I correctly collect all promises before calling `allProgress()`?

---

UPDATE

In the process of producing a MCVE, I came up with

```js
let promises = [];
[1,2,3].forEach(idx => {

    test(1000).then(promises.push(test(10000)));
});

console.log(promises.length);
// function to display the progress:
allProgress(promises,
  (p) => {
     console.log(`% Done = ${p.toFixed(2)}`);
});

function test(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Waited ${ms}`);
            resolve();
        }, ms);
    });
}

function allProgress(proms, progress_cb) {
    let d = 0;
    progress_cb(0);
    proms.forEach((p) => {
        p.then(() => {
            d++;
            progress_cb((d * 100) / proms.length);
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(proms);
}
```

This script, to my surprise, works... Why isn't equivalent to my original script?

---

UPDATE2

```
[1,2,3].forEach(idx => {
    test(1000).then(_ => {
        promises.push(test(10000))
    });
});
```

This should be the MCVE, which does not work.

Comment: Why not use `map` instead of `forEach` + `push`? That will also prevent your mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .find() function is async so while you are still in the process of finding elements the forEach loop itself moves on. In the end you end up waiting for your .find().

What you could do is inside of the .then() callback, check the index of the current forEach item, if you are at the last item then we know all promises have been returned. So call your allProgress function there.

This should allow enough time for waiting for everything to come together. Additionally, by checking against the index, we know that we will only call your allPromises function at completion. Not multiple times as each forEach loop occurs.

```js
let promises = [];
mylist.forEach((idx, index) => {
    myCollection.find({id: idx}).toArray().then(msgs => {
        promises.push(myCollection2.insertMany(msgs.map(msg => ({
            msg: msg,
            otherFields: others
        }))));
        if((index + 1) === mylist.length){
            // function to display the progress:
            allProgress(promises, (p) => {
                console.log(`% Done = ${p.toFixed(2)}`);
            });
        }
    })
});

function allProgress(proms, progress_cb) {
    let d = 0;
    progress_cb(0);
    proms.forEach((p) => {
      p.then(()=> {    
        d ++;
        progress_cb( (d * 100) / proms.length );
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(proms);
}
```

Edit:
Your MCVE (latest edit) is failing for the exact same reason. Your requests are async which is allowing the loop to progress without waiting. Once again, check the index and call when all done.

```js
let promises = [];
let entries = [1, 2, 3]
entries.forEach((idx, index) => {
    test(1000).then(_ => {
        promises.push(test(10000))
        if((index + 1) === entries.length) {
          console.log(promises.length);
          // function to display the progress:
          allProgress(promises,
            (p) => {
               console.log(`% Done = ${p.toFixed(2)}`);
          });
         }
    });
});

function test(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Waited ${ms}`);
            resolve();
        }, ms);
    });
}



function allProgress(proms, progress_cb) {
    let d = 0;
    progress_cb(0);
    proms.forEach((p) => {
        p.then(() => {
            d++;
            progress_cb((d * 100) / proms.length);
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(proms);
}
```

Comment: Note, had a slight typo, should be index + 1. Fixed in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

myCollection.find({id: idx}) is async operation.
 so you can like this:

```
let promises = [];
mylist.forEach(idx => {
    myCollection.find({id: idx}).toArray().then(msgs => {
       promises.push(myCollection2.insertMany(msgs.map(msg => ({
           msg: msg,
           otherFields: others
       }))))
      allProgress(promises,
        (p) => {
            console.log(`% Done = ${p.toFixed(2)}`);
      });
  })
});
function allProgress(proms, progress_cb) {
   let d = 0;
    progress_cb(0);
   proms.forEach((p) => {
     p.then(()=> {    
       d ++;
       progress_cb( (d * 100) / proms.length );
     });
   });
   return Promise.all(proms);
}
```

Comment: This is going to cause allPromises to get called every loop of the forEach, that could result in the same promises being executed multiple times.